# Where is Mr Bonding?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Mr Bonding is the guy that hands out O-Powers (such as Capture Power, or Attack Power) for you to use on your friends. However I've only found him twice, once in the Gateway to Route 5, and once in Hotel Ambrette (Ambrette Town).

So, what other locations does he show up in?

Comment: So far I've seen Mr. Bonding in every city or town in either a hotel or the Poké Center. Not too sure if I met him in Lumiose City, though...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Mr Bonding Locations

**Route 5**

- Attack Power
- Defense Power
- HP Restoring Power
- Capture Power

**Anistar City Pokémon Cente**

- Exp. Point Power

**Cyllage City Hotel**

- Prize Money Power

**Camphier Hotel**

- Sp. Attack Power

**Ambrette Hotel**

- Sp. Defense Power

**Dendemille Town Pokémon Center**

- Accuracy Power

**Geosenge Hotel**

- Speed Power

**Courmarine City Pokémon Center**

- Befriending Power

**Laverre City Pokémon Center**

- Encounter Power (NOTE: cannot be sent to other people)

**Couriway Town Hotel**

- Stealth Power (NOTE: cannot be sent to other people)

**Snowbelle City**

- PP Restoring Power

**Lumiose City - Hotel Richissime**

- Bargain Power

**Shalour City - Pokémon Center**

- Critical Power

Comment: I formatted this in the most backasswards way. Will have to reformat later.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a **Hatching O-Power**, which cuts the amount of steps needed to hatch eggs.

You must collect all the other O-Powers first, as well as have a high style-rating.

Once you have sufficient style, you can find Mr Bonding in **Café Introversion** (South Boulevard, Lumiose City)

I found that I needed to:

- Buy clothes from the Expensive Boutique
- Make a PR video
- Complete at least one of the courses at each restaurant (Le Nah/Yeah/Wow and Sushi High roller) with perfect timing (no more or less moves than what was stated for each course)
- The Hotel Richimme jobs (until the pay increases to $50k).

This brought the Mega Stone cost down to $50k, and Taxis were giving me discounts. Mr Bonding appeared in the Cafe Introversion as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have made it to the final gym, and have found him all subsequent times either in the upper right-most room of the town's hotel, ***or*** staring into the corner of the Poké Center by the changing room.