# Hold items used when breeding

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I specifically remember an item in one of the older games that would increase the chance of finding an egg when your Pokemon are at the daycare. But for the life of me, I cannot remember what that hold item was. Is this item still available in XY and if so, where can I find it? What other hold items are beneficial when breeding and what are there effects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Items

- **Destiny Knot** (Hold). Will guarantee that the parents pass on 5 IVs to the child.

  - The IVs are chosen individually from either parent, i.e. it doesn't matter which parent holds this.
  - The IVs chosen are randomed from each parent, i.e. One time you might get 4 from the father, 1 from the mother, another time you'll get 3 from the mother, two from the father and so on.
  - The IV not chosen will be generated normally, thus it is possible to generate a full IV in this case as well)
- **Everstone** (Hold) - Will guarantee that the child has the same **[Nature](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nature)** as the parent that holds it.
- **Power items** (Hold) - Will guarantee the specific stat IV from the holding parent is passed on.

  - Items can be bought with Battle Points (BP) from the Battle Maison. They cost 16BP each
  - When used in conjunction with Destiny Knot, the Power item's affected stat is counted against the 5 copied by destiny knot.
  - The items include:

    1. Power Weight (HP)
    2. Power Bracer (Atk)
    3. Power Belt (Def)
    4. Power Lens (SpA)
    5. Power Band (SpD)
    6. Power Anklet (Spe)
- **Oval Charm** (Key Item) - Increases the chances of Pokemon in daycare producing an Egg.

  - Awarded from Professor Sycamore upon completion of the Kalos Pokedex
- **Shiny Charm** (Key Item) - Increases the chance of breeding a shiny Pokemon off the two parents are from different language (known as the Masuda method). It also increases the chance of shiny encounter in the wild. It is awarded after getting (not only seeing) all Pokemon from the national dex (minus event only Pokemon) from the professor.

### Other

- **Flame Body** (Ability) - Halves the amount of steps needed to hatch eggs.

  - Talonflame works well for this, as it also doubles as a flier, meaning you can leave 5 empty party slots for eggs.
- **Hatching O-Power** (O-power) - Cuts the amount of steps needed to hatch eggs.

  - Awarded upon collection of all the [other O-Powers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135856/where-is-mr-bonding), as well with high style-rating (around $50k-$10k for mega stones)
  - Find Mr Bonding in Café Introversion (South Boulevard, Lumiose City)

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [Oval Charm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Oval_Charm#Oval_Charm). You need to complete the Kalos Dex to get it from the professor. Good luck!

It's a key item, so it just sits in your bag while your Pokemon keep busy in the daycare :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion sake, shiny charm is missing from the list.
You get it after getting (not just seeing) all the Pokemon from the national dex (minus event only Pokemon) from the professor.
It's a key item too, so no hold item.
If you are breeding two Pokemon from different languages, the probability the offspring will be shiny is increased.
It also increases the probability of shiny encounter in the wild.

Comment: You are able to edit the list in that answer with this item, so that there is a single answer with everything included