# Power Lens not working for IV breeding?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I am a bit new to IV breeding and I am trying to breed a flawless Lucario.

- The male is holding the Destiny Knot with 3 perfect IVs (Attack, Sp. Defense, and Speed).
- The female is holding Power Lens with 3 perfect IVs (HP, Sp. Defense, and Speed).

I have read that using Power Items guarantee a perfect IV in the stat it boosts. After I a few batches of eggs I have not received one offspring with Sp.Attack (which the power lens boosts). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And to explain the result, your Riolu are getting the SpAtk IV of the female Lucario, which, from your question, is not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look from the answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/150207/80141). It is **not** guaranteed that the IV is perfect, but it is passed down from the parent that is holding the item. If the female has an IV of 14 (for example), the offspring will also have an IV of 14. Of course the IV is perfect, when the female's IV is perfect.

Bottomline, **power items pass down the IV**, not make it perfect.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that an IV is a hidden stat ranging from 0 to 31.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EV-enhancing_item):

> If **Power Lens** is held by a parent when breeding at the Day Care Center the Special Attack IV of the parent holding this item will be passed down to the baby.

As *Mathias711* mentioned, your offspring will inherit the parent's actual value of Special Attack.

Anyway, if you want to breed a perfect Lucario it's recommended to have a Lucario with good IVs and a 6IVs Ditto. In this case you will easily end up with a flawless Riolu in few offsprings.

What's more important is that you should give your parents Destiny Knot (to ensure that 5IVs will be passed down) and the Everstone (to transfer the Nature).