# What is the lowest price that the Mega Stone man will sell the stones for?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'd like to buy the Mega Stones as cheap as possible. Like the title states, how low will the Mega Stone man in Lumiose City Stone Emporium drop his prices for the Starter Mega Stones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest he has gone so far for myself is $10,000. This is after I have:

- Completed the Looker missions
- Become a 'fully qualified attendant' at Hotel Richimme ($50,000 a job)
- Completed all restaurant double/triple battle meals with the required number of moves (yet to do rotation battles)
- Bought an outfit from Boutique Couture
- Created 3 PR videos (one in each slot)
- Received the [Hatching O-power](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/150211/28182) from Mr Bonding
- Got a haircut
- had my Furfrou styled

Here is a picture:
[image: Picture of the Mega Stone man offering Blastoiseite for $10000]

Comment: Pretty dang sure it's $10,000. And all you really need to do is do the "buy lots of pokeballs" at the pokeball emporium trick to get there

Comment: @BenBrocka This is what I did, you pointed this out to me before. I bought 100 premier balls, one at a time. And my style was then maxed so the price for the stones was $10K

Comment: @BenBrocka - yeah I bought about 70, and got from $100k to $50k, but I forgot to save and my battery ran out. So I avoided doing that again lol